# Open DrawerLayout, perform action, then close it

Tags: android, animation, drawerlayout

So I want to animate my DrawerLayout in such a way that it is opened, an item is added to the menu in it, then it is closed.

I tried a great deal of things, but the problem is that there is no delay between the "Open" and "Close" commands (or at least not a noticeable one) and so the animation never triggers.

I really don't want to use a 'post delayed' with an arbitrary length because that seems dirty.
I've tried manually overriding "onDrawerOpened()" in the listener - which WORKED, but then I can't CLOSE it AFTER the action is performed because you can't close it from within itself (meaning, if the 'closeDrawer(layout)' method is invoked from any sub-thread of the listener itself, it'll get a runtime error).

So what I have is:

```
 _drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(MainActivity.this, _drawerLayout, R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.drawerOpen, R.string.drawerClose)
 {
      /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state. */
      public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
           getActionBar().setTitle(_title);
      }

       /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
      public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
           myAction(); //My action                            
           //If I try to invoke 'drawerClose()' here or in my action, a runtime error occurs
      }
 };
 _drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(_drawerToggle);
 _drawerLayout.openDrawer(_mainFrame);
 //If I invoke 'drawerClose()' the entire thing is just too fast and the animations don't trigger
```

I even tried 'getAnimation()' on the DrawerLayout but it returns null so I can't use it to post a delayed action.

Anyone have an idea how to approach this? Should I just used an arbitrary delay and hope it looks the same on all devices? Is there a way to close the drawer from within the listener?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Calling `closeDrawer()` isn't working in `onDrawerOpened()` because, well, the drawer hasn't finished opening. If you watch `onDrawerStateChanged()` you'll notice the state still changes after `onDrawerOpened()` is called.

I tried closing the drawer when `onDrawerStateChanged()` said the drawer was idle, however it still crashed. My final solution looks, as you said, hacky. But it works, and looks smooth. This should be placed in `onDrawerOpened()`

```
new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        SystemClock.sleep(500);
        MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
            }
        });
    }
}.start();
```

This could probably look a little better if you use some sort or thread manager, like the one posted here

https://gist.github.com/bclymer/6708605

Disclaimer, that's my utility class. I use it in most of my apps though, it's very convenient. With the utility the code would look like

```
ThreadManager.delayOnMainThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();           
    }
}, 500);
```

Comment: I ended up opting for a similar solution. I can't believe there isn't a more elegant way to accomplish this, but heck - what works, works. Thanks!

Comment: @EladAvron there is a lot more elegant, like using the build in getContentView().postDelayed(Runnable, int) if your in an Activity? (You can use postDelayed on any view actually)